# Bootstrap 4 Carousel with HTML 5 picture tag instead of img tag works?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Does Bootrap 4 Carousel support below HTML as child of carousel-item:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

This will allow webp images to be servred instead of JPEG to by browsers that support webp.

Comment: Did you try using it on Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work if you will put a picture tag code in Carousel item if any browser will not support then jpg will display at the same place but Carousel will work.